# How to represent guillemets in `org-mode`: Unicode vs Org-mode entities)?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, unicode, characters

I was planning to write some narrative in Emacs, and after a bit of research it seems that the most complete solution may be `org-mode`. Now, I report direct speech using guillemets (`«` and `»`). The problem is choosing a method to insert them in my text.

Usually I would simply use double angle brackets, but `org-mode` treats those as links. I thought that a good solution may be setting an `abbrev`, so that `<<` gets converted to `«`.

Now, my point is: I can set the expansion to the **unicode point** for the guillemet (`U+00ab` and `U+00bb`), or I can use **`org-entities`** (`\laquo` and `\raquo`, together with `org-toggle-pretty-entities`).

What are the advantages for choosing each of those two approaches?

Comment: Both will work: try each one, see which is easier to use for you, make sure that exporting to the formats you are interested in works properly. If after that you still don't have a preference, flip a coin!

Comment: Thanks! So, basically there isn't a best practice for it, am I right? Like, known bugs?

Comment: None that I know of. When you try them out, if you hit any bugs, report them!

Comment: The question is too broad. Ask a more specific question, saying specifically what you want the result to be used for.

Comment: Thanks to both! Yep, I didn't have a specific use case in mind, I was just wondering if one had proven more reliable than the other. Anyway, thanks. Should I mark the question as closed, or write an answer for it?